Run all PyTest assertions even with multiple failures (No option to split tests)
I'm working with PyTest to test system readiness for application installation and I want to ensure all assertions in a test run, even if some of them fail. The main reason for that these tests are run by support team which are not technical so they wanted to know about all missing items in system before they proceed for installations.
Unfortunately, I don't have the option to break down the test into separate ones for each assertion. I tried multiple options like  --maxfail=n but this option is not tests included in test suites not for single test.
Test rerun is not a option also, as it always give same kind of failure.
Is there a recommended way to achieve this behavior in PyTest?
I am using following version:

Python: 3.8.10
Pytest 8.1.1

import subprocess

import pytest

def test_executable_script():
    result = subprocess.check_output([executable_script], encoding="UTF-8")
    assert result != "", f"Error: {result}"

    result_2 = subprocess.check_output([another_executable_script], encoding="UTF-8")
    assert result != "", f"Error: {result}"



You cannot achieve this behavior: an assert raises an exception that causes the test function to exit. The only solution would be to rewrite the test so that you only have a single assert at the end, or split it into multiple tests.

what is the purpose of testing if one is going to let assertions that fail turn into passes ?  then why bother asserting in the first place ?

you might wish to fix the code indentation so that the intention is clear and the example works...

Does this answer your question? How do I convert a unittest subtest to pytest

@D.L I have to write some test cases for support team for verification of our system before proceed with application installation. So they needs complete information about it.

You can create a list for failures and assert on that list. Here is how to achieve it.
import subprocess
import pytest


def test_executable_script():
    _fails = []

    result = subprocess.check_output([executable_script], encoding="UTF-8")
 
    if result == "":
        _fails.append("Error1")

    result_2 = subprocess.check_output([another_executable_script],encoding="UTF-8")

    if result_2 == "":
        _fails.append("Error2")

    assert not _fails, "Test failed because of: {}".format(" - ".join(_fails))


The best way to achieve what you want is parametrize
@pytest.mark.parametrize("script", ["executable_script", "another_executable_script"])
def test_executable_script(script):
    result = subprocess.check_output([script], encoding="UTF-8")
    assert result != "", f"Error: {result}"

